# How to truncate equation with multivariables

Tags: replacement, indexed-variable

I am trying to set certain terms zero. How to set terms with greater than 'a3' and 'an3' zero in the following equation:

```
eq=(ω1^2 + I γ (ωd + 3 ωp) - (ωd + 3 ωp)^2) a3[t] + 1/2 Γ1 (a2[t] + a4[t]) +  1/2 Λ (a2[t] + a4[t]) + (ω1^2 + I γ (ωd - 3 ωp) - (ωd - 3 ωp)^2) an3[t] + 1/2 Γ1 (an2[t] + an4[t]) + 1/2 Λ (an2[t] + an4[t]) + (γ + 
2 I (ωd + 3 ωp)) Derivative[1][a3][t] + (γ + 2 I (ωd - 3 ωp)) Derivative[1][an3][t]
```

I have tried the following:

```
    eq/. {am[n_ /; Abs[n] > nLimit][t] -> 0, bm[n_ /; Abs[n] > nLimit][t] -> 0,
am[n_ /; Abs[n] > nLimit]'[t] -> 0, bm[n_ /; Abs[n] > nLimit]'[t] -> 0}
```

Where

```
nLimit=3;
am[numberOfR_] := If[numberOfR >= 0, Symbol["a" <> ToString[numberOfR]], 
Symbol["an" <> ToString[Abs[numberOfR]]]];
bm[numberOfR_] :=   If[numberOfR >= 0, Symbol["a" <>ToString[numberOfR]],Symbol["an" <> ToString[Abs[numberOfR]]]];
```

But It did not work

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "with greater than 'a3' and 'an3' zero", it is not clear at all. Could you rewrite it?

Comment: So, an4[t], an5[t],a4[t],a5[t] should be zero

Comment: @parmeshwar89 its better if you [edit] your question and give a good explanation, even if you have an answer, so it becomes useful for other people too.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, maybe you should first rewrite your `a1,a2,..` as `a[1], a[2], ...`, then it is much easier to test.

A simple example:

```
eq = a[1][t] + a[2][t] + a[3][t] + a[4][t]
```

then

```
eq /. { a[n_ /; n >= 3][t] -> 0  }
```

> `a[1][t] + a[2][t]`

Comment: a1,a2, an1,an2 ... are variables.If anybody can tell me how to generate subscripted numbered variables. That could also work

Comment: @parmeshwar89 - Use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html): `Format[a[n_]]  :=  Subscript[a, n]`

Comment: @parmeshwar89 see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128055/19960) from @Bob concerning `Format`